# How to integrate Foursquare in android

Tags: android, foursquare

Please tell me is there any way to integrate Foursquare in android. Can you give me some idea or link to integrate Foursquare in android?

Please help.

Answer (score 5):

This project is another good starting point:
https://github.com/jiramot/foursquare-android-sdk

Answer (score 4):

What u need is follow documentation at https://developer.foursquare.com/ 
You need to make use of JSON and OAuth2 libraries for Android to help you do it faster.

For JSON use Android default and OAuth2 u can look here https://bitbucket.org/smartproject/oauth-2.0/wiki/Home

Answer (score 2):

In addition to making API requests to the Foursquare API, you can have your app open the Foursquare app itself by publishing one of the Intents listed on [this page](https://developer.foursquare.com/resources/client#android)

Answer (score 0):

Or try this [Application](http://codecanyon.net/item/android-startup-application-/243698).